# Is there a formula I can use to return 0 value if another cell has zero value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Need to display sale price minus cost in the current cell (profit). If the sale price is zero (not sold) display `0`. Output (profit is then totalled elsewhere. So total should only reflect items sold. This is to be done in Google Sheets.

Comment: pls provide an example and copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

there is an `IF` formula which can do exactly what you are asking for:

```
=IF(A1=0, 0, )
```

**https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en**